# Why bother with server-side hit detection?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, anti-cheat, shooter

[Valve's hit detection](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) tracks player positions from when the bullet fired and then tells clients only whether the hit happened, but I can't see why that is necessary in the first place. Does server-side hit detection do anything but slow down the action?

What is the purpose of server-side hit detection when malicious players could cheat with an aimbot anyway?

Comment: It sounds like this measure is not to stop aimbots, it's to stop the (much worse) problem of being able to craft a packet that says "I hit you" over and over until you die, regardless of whether or not I can see you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Server-side hit detection isn't to prevent aimbots, it's to prevent cheaters who simply tell the server "I hit!" regardless of where they are aiming.